# IRay Server web interface has significant lag when run under Ubuntu Server, but is fine on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: 22.04

So the title pretty much spells it out. I'm running [IRay Server](https://www.irayplugins.com/iray-server/), and while the app might be significant I have a feeling it's something else going on.

Long story short; if I install Ubuntu Desktop, and spin up this service, everything runs fine.

If I do the same on Ubuntu Server, the internal processes of this server run just fine. But the web interface it presents runs super slow. Like 5-10 seconds from when I click anywhere in the UI until the server reacts.

There are no particular clues in the log to indicate there is a problem.

The installation process differs slightly. On Ubuntu Desktop, I can install the server and run it. Although, I do need to update my NVidia Drivers.

Currently, this would look like this:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-545 nvidia-dkms-545
```

On Ubuntu Server, it's a little bit more involved. Mostly because I'm not all that experienced with Ubuntu Server; but I do this to get things going:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal`
```

Apparently, some openGL dependencies are missing if I do not do this. Then I do as before.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-545 nvidia-dkms-545
```

And that's it.

The lags in the web UI feel "timeout-y" to me if that makes any sense. I don't know. I don't know where to start looking for the root cause, so I guess the question is - is there something obvious the way web apps would be handled, on Server versus Desktop?

Or is anyone familiar enough with IRay Server to perhaps have a suggestion?